# extract data from XML response w/PHP

Tags: php, xml, variables, simplexml

When I get an API response containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response xmlns="http://www.XXXXXXX.com/api/" status="ok">
  <client_id>17992</client_id>
</response>
```

I can get the results of the `<client_id>` using this.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($server_output);
$client = (string) $xml->client_id;
echo $client; // produces 17992 in this case
```

but if I add this below, I do not get a value assigned to $response.

```
$response = (string) $xml->response; // produces empty value
```

How do I write the PHP code to check if XML response "status" = OK?

Comment: @skrilled  Thank you, That worked. Write it as a response instead of a comment and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work great for you :)

```
$xml['status'];
```

Answer (score 3):

see this on simple applications of `simplexml`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

To access attributes of a node, do:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
echo $xml['status'];
```

or loop through all attributes:

```
foreach ($xml->attributes() as $name => $value)
    echo "$name: $value <br />";
```

see it in action: https://eval.in/40185